# Python: I tried to use tabula: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'

Tags: python, module, tabula

I tried to use the module "tabula" for python, but apparently I already fail at installing. I simply used the code

```
import tabula
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'
```

Any ideas what's up with that?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install it priorly, lauching this command in a console:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

Edit:

For WIndows 10, check the "Get tabula-py working (Windows 10)" part of [this documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that, but I get the message

The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install tabula-py


Right now, I'm using Spyder, maybe that's the problem??? Sorry, if it's a super naive question

Comment: Which message do you get?

Comment: The following command must be run outside of the IPython shell:

    $ pip install tabula-py

The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of IPython.
Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or command prompt.

See the Python documentation for more information on how to install packages:

    https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Comment: In which terminal did you launch that? On which Operating System?

Comment: I have Windows 10, and I just used the console in the Spyder IDE ..?

Comment: I completed my answer for Windows 10 ;)

Comment: Thank you so much that's very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but I solved it by running 'ipython3' instead of 'ipython'.
You have to make sure running the script with python3

Answer (score -1):

This line of code is what worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py
```