# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'. After trying many things

Tags: python, installation, module, tabula

Yes, I know this question has been asked in the past, twice. Still I tried all the ideas that were proposed plus ideas from other websites and yet it still doesn't work, so here I go:

I have windows 10, python 3.8.3 and java 1.8.0_261.

I tried first pip install tabula-py.
Then I tried pip install tabula_py.
Then I tried to find the version of java in cmd which it didn't find. I then added a path (I found on the internet) to the settings in "My PC" and then I did find the version of java.
I tried to restart my computer.
I tried pip uninstall tabula-py and then pip3 install tabula-py

But still, when I run "import tabula" in jupyter notebook, it says he can't find this module. I have searched the entire internet and tried everything suggested but with no luck. Can anyone please help me?

Links to the other 2 questions I went over:
[Python: I tried to use tabula: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741605/python-i-tried-to-use-tabula-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tabula)
[Tabula-py - ImportError: No module named tabula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596477/tabula-py-importerror-no-module-named-tabula)

Comment: "this question has been asked in the past, twice": could you provide links to those questions, and possibly comment on how or why it didn't work for you?

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install tabula-py`, then run `python3 -m jupyter notebook`, see how that goes. This way should ensure that you're not accidentally dealing with multiple Python versions between pip and jupyter.

Comment: I commented in one of those questions but it got deleted by an admin.
Things that were suggested was to add the path, to use pip3 install and to check that all my versions are high enough. I referred to all of this in my question now to make it as clear as possible.
I now also tried the 2 commands you wrote in cmd but they both don't seem to do anything, it just starts a new line in cmd. Am I doing anything wrong or should I be running it somewhere else? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I would expect `python3 -m pip install tabula-py` to at least show some output; try with the `--verbose` option added. The `python3 -m jupyter notebook` command should either start a Jupyter notebook, or give an error. If nothing happens, there is a problem with your setup. What does just `python3` result in?

Comment: Also, please add the two related links to your question, just so people know what hasn't worked for you.

Comment: Okay will do! This is the what I wrote in command prompt and it's outputs. The only thing that happened was that my applications screen was opened and it showed the option of opening python.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.959]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\97253>python3 -m pip install tabula-py

C:\Users\97253>python3 -m jupyter notebook

C:\Users\97253>python3

C:\Users\97253>python3 --m pip install tabula-py

Comment: C:\Users\97253>pip3 install tabula-py
Requirement already satisfied: tabula-py in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: distro in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from tabula-py) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.25.3 in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from tabula-py) (0.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from tabula-py) 1.19.0

Comment: continuation:
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25.3->tabula-py) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.25.3->tabula-py) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\97253\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas>=0.25.3->tabula-py) (1.15.0)

C:\Users\97253>

Comment: You can edit your question, which allows for better formatting than in comments. Also, I see `python3 --m pip install tabula-py` instead of `python3 -m pip install tabula-py` (note: extra dash), and then below that, you still ran `pip3 install tabula-py`. From your comment "it showed the option of opening python", it sounds as if there was/is a slight problem with your python3 installation itself, it there isn't any other output.

Answer (score 2):

So in the end I found yet another link with a line of code that did work!

conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py

To my dissapointment I have no idea why this works and why the other suggested code didn't, as cmd is not my specialty. If anyone understands and could explain what the issue was or what the difference is, I would love to hear. Thank you

Source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tabula-py
I only ran the first line

Answer (score 0):

Does the "conda" only work in a specific environment ?
Because I try command in vs_code but show errors about "conda" is unrecognized command...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30733847)